# Android Text To Speech - Highlight spoken words

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my UtteranceProgressListener I have overrided the `onRangeStart` but it's not getting called.

```
       @Override
        public void onRangeStart(String utteranceId, int start, int end, int frame) {
            super.onRangeStart(utteranceId, start, end, frame);

            Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(smartOcrDisplayTextLeft.getText());
            wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

            smartOcrDisplayTextLeft.setText(wordToSpan);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the code was correct. From the settings -> Accessibility to you need to select Google as Text-to-Speech engine.

Answer (score 2):

According to the UtteranceProgressListener [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener), "The callbacks specified in this method can be called from multiple threads."

To verify this, you can add

```
boolean wasCalledFromBackgroundThread = (Thread.currentThread().getId() != 1);
                Log.i("XXX", "was onRangeStart() called on a background thread? : " + wasCalledFromBackgroundThread);
```

to the onRangeStart() method body.

In my experience, they are called on background threads more often than not.

So, it would be safer to surround the UI manipulation like so:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(smartOcrDisplayTextLeft.getText());
        wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        smartOcrDisplayTextLeft.setText(wordToSpan);

    }
 });
```

Comment: Yes, it's been a while since I worked with this... but I verified and edited answer.

Comment: You 1 means the main thread and anything else is background? Hmm quite insightful. I didn't know that before. Thanks